# Where should domain events be added: in entities or aggregate roots?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm designing the base classes and I don't know if I should add the field 'domainEvents' to the Entity class or only to the AggregateRoot class.

I must add the code for add and remove events in Entity.cs or AggregateRoot.cs

```
private List<INotification> _domainEvents;
public IReadOnlyCollection<INotification> DomainEvents => _domainEvents;
public void AddDomainEvent(INotification eventItem) {}
public void RemoveDomainEvent(INotification eventItem) {}
```

Comment: can you add some details about what you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Michael I have edited the post.

Comment: ok.. but still. This could be a "customer relationship management" system. It could be a "game engine". You could be writing a device driver. You could be creating an SVG-to-WebGL-converter. It could be about a speech recognition software.

Comment: I agree with Michael.  The goal is not necessarily to fulfill the tenets of DDD, it is to satisfy your specific software requirements.

Comment: The way you asked this question reveals a common misunderstanding: that questions of this kind can be sensible answered by exclusively looking at the code structure, just by some braindead, formal aspects (no offense!). Sorry, but that does not work. You need to think what these events are about, what kind of change in your system they shall notify about, and who or what shall consume them. Then you can decide where to implement them in the most sensible manner.

Comment: Here’s a better question: From a consumer’s point of view, is there a difference between an `Entity` and an `AggregateRoot`? If so, why?

Comment: @king-side-slide Yes and no; a consumer only can modify the database with aggregate roots.

Comment: @DocBrown My business is not working with DDD right now and I am learning with *demos* without a good architecture or good base classes. I have programmed Entity.cs, AggregateRoot.cs, Enumeration.cs, ValueObject.cs and a lot of classes for my architecture. If you can help me, it's ok, but I am learning DDD, and with effort.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't know in what scenarios I should have events in the aggregate root and in one entity too. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: The point of domain driven design is to focus on the domain, and make decisions based on that. If you cannot come up with a real example for a domain, you cannot do domain driven design. I would go even further than that: deciding what your project is all about should be the first decision for any project. - If you want to learn DDD, pick a domain first. Everything else will be a waste of your time. - I have done DDD for years, but I never heard of "aggregate roots"; I have used some "value objects", but having a file named "ValueObject.cs" feels wrong.

Comment: @Michael My domain is a online store. Have you never heard about aggregate roots? Then you never did DDD.

Comment: @Michael: The "Aggregate Root" can be thought of as the "bootstrapper" or "main() method" of an aggregate.  It contains whatever machinery is required to stand up a particular aggregate.  See https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html

Comment: @JhonDuck storing a collection of domain events in an entity (aggregate root or otherwise) is very uncommon in "vanilla" DDD. It can be a thing in Event Sourced DDD domains, but probably not in the same form as your example.

Comment: The term “aggregate root” is used to help us *conceptually* understand how an object manages its state and is therefore an idea orthogonal to that of an `Entity` (which is concerned with identity). An `Entity` may or may not be an aggregate root, just like any other object charged with being the sole, unambiguous, and authoritative representation of the data it contains. There is no utility at all in defining a separate class file, and in fact is simply creating the problem we are discussing.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on your domain model and the purpose of these events.

Maybe it could make sense to add domain event to aggregate roots only, if the purpose is to handle events that affect the aggregate as a whole.

But maybe it could make sense to add them to relevant entity classes within the aggregate. Take the usual `Car` aggregate example, with `Wheels` and `Engine` being entities. It could then make sense to add events at entity level, to handle events that are related to the tire pressure or the engine temperature.